# If I use LGPL-licensed images in my open-source software project, do I have to use the LGPL for the whole project?

Tags: licensing

...or, can I license things separately within the project (i.e. images=LGPL, code=GPL).  I've been confused about this for a little while now and I can't seem to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very common, and with GPL-style software licenses almost a requirement, to use different licenses for the source code and the artwork/images.

Just like that Creative Commons licenses are a bad fit for software, software copyright licenses are also a bad fit for non-software works, like images.
Especially the LGPL is a bad fit for images, because the clauses about linking, that separate it from the GPL, don't seem to have a meaning for images but they might have unexpected legal consequences.

The best option for a project that consists of both software and images is to use separate licenses for the two parts, with a Creative Commons license for the images and a software license (like GPL) for the code.

As far as copyright is concerned, the code and images can be regarded as separate works and that is the reason you can use separate licenses.